# OpenCart 3 Не загружаются файлы из архива ocmod

Tags: opencart, opencart3.x

Столкнулся с проблемой, не могу разобраться, что я делаю не так. OpenCart 3.0.3.2.
Я немного расширил функционал магазина. Всю работу я сделал в оригинальных файлах и все работает, как я и хотел. Захотелось познакомиться с ocmod и я подумал всю работу сделать с помощью модификатора. На данный момент я оставил все работающие файлы на своих местах и убрал только 1 файл по пути admin/controller/extension/module/test.php. Если вернуть его на место, то в Extensions->modules появится название моего, так сказать, модуля.

Что я сделал:

Создал zip архив test.ocmod
В архиве находятся файл install.xml и папка upload.

В папке upload/admin/controller/extension/module/ есть файл test.php тот, который я убрал. Для теста я хочу его вернуть на свое место с помощью "Installer".

В файле install.xml вот что:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
    <name>Test</name>
    <code>test</code>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <link>test.test</link>
    <author>Test</author>
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/common/header.twig">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[
            {{ language }}
            ]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
            {{ test }}
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>  
</modification>
```

Установка проходит отлично. в Install History появляется запись. В модификаторе и в Developer Settings обновляю все, что есть.

И вот сама проблема:

В Modification List - ничего нет.
В Extensions->modules - ничего нет.
По пути system/storage/modification кроме системных папок и файла index.html - тоже ничего нет.

ocmod.log

```
2020-03-24 14:05:40 - MOD: Modification Default

FILE: system/engine/action.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 69

FILE: system/engine/loader.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 77
LINE: 151
LINE: 168

FILE: system/library/config.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 59

FILE: system/library/language.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 67
LINE: 73

FILE: system/library/template/template.php
REGEX: ~(require|include)(_once)?\(([^)]+)~
LINE: 18

FILE: system/library/template/twig.php
CODE: $loader = new \Twig_Loader_Filesystem(DIR_TEMPLATE);
LINE: 19
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Я подумал, что это связано с тем, что я не перенес папку storage за пределы каталога сайта. Только что вынес эту папку, загрузил архив снова, но кроме системных папок и файлов ничего в папке modification нет.

Если поместить файл модификатор в папку System, то изменения применяются. Но мне хотелось бы разобраться с загрузкой архива через установщик.

Уже не знаю, что пробовать. Читал, что бывает проблема с неправильно настроенным FTP, на 2-ке видел эту вкладку, а на 3-ке не вижу. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не правильно, или в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Может кто-то наступит на такие же грабли, вот решение моей проблемы.
Я неправильно упаковал архив. Мой архив выглядел так:

```
test.ocmod.zip
-test.ocmod
--upload
--install.xml
```

перепаковал так:

```
test.ocmod.zip
-upload
-install.xml
```

И еще удалил пробелы в xml и все заработало:

```
<search><![CDATA[{{ language }}]]></search>
```